# Is the Darmok Episode the only time we see Tamarians?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

The Tamarians are very interesting and I'm hoping to see more of them. Are they in any other Star Trek episode, movie, or perhaps novelization?

After looking at the memory-alpha wikia, I am only seeing examples from the Darmok episode, however, I'm not sure if memory-alpha covers novelizations.

Comment: As indicated at the bottom of the Memory Alpha article on Tamarians, licensed works (such as novels) are covered on Memory Beta, and there is an article on Tamarians there: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Tamarian Per that article, Tamarians are mentioned in a few stories, and one appears in a Voyager novel.

Comment: I wish that there were multiple canon showings of every Star Trek species (yes, including the Edo). Perhaps the exception would be the space hippies from that forgettable TOS episode.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - They should have set the next series on Risa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Main Canon

The Children of Tama appear in the episodes

- [TNG: Darmok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Children_of_Tama) (Picard and the Tamarian captain fight the beast)
- [LD: Kayshon, His Eyes Open](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kayshon,_His_Eyes_Open_(episode)) (That specific episode is centred around a Tamarian security officer aboard the Cerritos. He then appears as a minor character in multiple episodes)

### EU Canon

The Tamarians make a number of appearances in other media;

- As the main characters in the short story [Friends With the Sparrows](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Friends_With_the_Sparrows)
- There's a Tamarian character in the novel [Voyager: Unworthy](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Unworthy)
- There are brief mentions of the Tamarian's progress toward Federation membership in the novels [War Stories, Book 1](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/War_Stories,_Book_1) and [Articles of the Federation](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Articles_of_the_Federation)
- They also feature as one of the playable races in [Star Trek Online](https://www.stoacademy.com/guides/alien/tamarian.php).

Comment: That STO entry is not accurate. Its actually settings to use the game's generic "Alien" race to get something that LOOKS like a Tamarian, but it isn't acknowledged as one in any way by the game itself. You have to do the same thing with Vorta, Cardassians, Ocampa, and many other races. The game actually only has about a dozen races.

Comment: Pretty sure Kayshon also appears in other LD episodes.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov - You're not wrong. See edit

Answer (score 7):

Episodes of the animated: *Star Trek: Lower Decks* introduce a security officer, [Kayshon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kayshon), that is Tamarian. He will often use the metaphor phrases, but his universal translator also allows him to speak and listen normally

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You could improve your answer by naming the character and giving a specific episode (or two) in which he features.